# Xetex Hebrew PDF output problem in Lyx

Tags: xetex, lyx, pdf, hebrew

I am trying to compile a document that contains both English and Hebrew. The problem is, that although I have selected **Documents | Settings | Use non-tex fonts via XeTeX |LuaTeX**, there is no option to export the file to PDF via Xetex (LuaTex always gives me all sorts of errors about not recognizing fonts). I then tried to see if XeTeX is installed, by entering the following into a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
```

In case it helps/matters: I'm running Lyx 2.0 on a Linux Mint machine. An extensive search, unfortunately, yielded no answers that worked.

So, my question is: How can I export the document to PDF via XeTeX (I only have the LuaTeX option)?

(P.S. If this question has been previously answered, I'd greatly appreciate a link to the page!)

Comment: The option `File -> Export -> PDF (XeTeX)` doesn't appear for you?

Comment: Can you post a minimal LyX example? If I open examples/splash.lyx, I am allowed to export using the menu as @juliohm suggested. You might want to try the latest version of LyX (e.g. LyX 2.1 beta 1). I don't know how it works on Mint, but for Ubuntu you can easily install other versions without interfering with your current versions. They can exist peacefully together: http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3

Comment: Also note my export of the Hebrew splash.lyx fails. If you find a solution or have suggestions on how I could successfully export splash.lyx with XeTeX on Ubuntu, please let me know so I can add this to LyX's tests.

Comment: @ juliohm: Correct, this option doesn't appear for me. I only get the option to export via LuaTex

Comment: @scottkosty: I wrote a sample file in Lyx, where the following appears when I click on "View Source"@ % Preview source code for paragraph 0

\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}%
This is a test \R{זה ניסוי}\selectlanguage{hebrew}%

\end{document}               If I find a way round this issue, I'll post it.

Comment: @juliohm: Silly me, I forgot to click on "reconfigure" once I installed Xetex. It now magically appears!!

Comment: Good news. And does it compile correctly for you with XeTeX? Did you install extra fonts? If so, which ones?

Comment: @scottkosty: I'm using Linux Mint Olivia (It's ok...I've told my wife about Olivia!!!). I installed Lyx by typing: 'sudo apt-get install lyx' and it worked very well for English. I also installed Culmus (using the same sudo command as above but using 'lyx culmus' instead of 'lyx'. Unfortunately, it still doesn't compile. I get a list of polyglossia errors that say that it doesn't recognise the font.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the font. For an example, do the following. After

```
sudo apt-get install culmus culmus-fancy
```

in LyX go to File > Open, click on the `examples` button, click on `he` and open `splash.lyx`. Then go to Document Settings > Fonts, check `Use non-TeX fonts` and for all of the fonts, choose `Frank Ruehl CLM` (this was installed by the `culmus` package, along with several others). Finally, change `Article (Hebrew)` to `article` and compile.

The last change is necessary because (although I'm not sure why), XeTeX does not seem to like the following (which is added by `Article (Hebrew)`:

```
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}
```

Following the above steps leads to the following pdf

[image]

produced by the following code:

```
%% LyX 2.1.0dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\setmonofont{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\providecommand{\LyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\frenchspacing

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\title{ברוכים הבאים ל- \textenglish{\LyX{}}}

\maketitle

\section*{כמה נקודות שחשוב לדעת על שימוש ב- \textenglish{\protect\LyX{}}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textenglish{\LyX{}} מגיע עם מסמכי תיעוד ועזרה מצויינים \textenglish{—}
מומלץ להשתמש בהם. כדאי להתחיל בקריאת הקובץ \textsf{עזרה$\vartriangleleft$מבוא},
המהווה הקדמה קצרה לתיעוד. לאחר מכן, ניתן להמשיך בקריאת \textsf{עזרה$\vartriangleleft$השיעור~המודרך}
על מנת ללמוד איך להשתמש ב- \textenglish{\LyX{}}.
\item אנחנו מתייחסים אל \textenglish{\LyX{}} כאל \char`\"{}מעבד מסמכים\char`\"{}.
הוא מתוכנן להיות שונה ממעבד תמלילים רגיל כך שמלאכת כתיבת המסמכים תהיה
קלה יותר. מסמכי העזרה והתיעוד יבהירו לך סוגיה זו%
\footnote{האם כבר הזכרנו כמה חשוב לקרוא אותם?%
}.
\item הפלט שיוצא מ- \textenglish{\LyX{}} נראה פשוט נהדר \textenglish{—}
לחץ על \textsf{תצוגה}$\vartriangleleft$\textenglish{\textsf{Dvi}}
וראה בעצמך.
\item \textenglish{\LyX{}} מסוגל לחקות (כמעט) את כל האפשרויות של \textenglish{\LaTeX{}},
והוא מסוגל לייבא קבצי \textenglish{\LaTeX{}}. משתמשי \textenglish{\LaTeX{}}
מנוסים יכולים לפיכך לקרוא את \char`\"{}השיעור המודרך\char`\"{} ברפרוף
ולהעמיק בחלק ''\textenglish{\LyX{}} למשתמשי \textenglish{\LaTeX{}}\char`\"{}
(כל השאר אל תדאגו! לא צריך לדעת \textenglish{\LaTeX{}} בשביל להשתמש
ב- \textenglish{\LyX{}}).
\item \textenglish{\LyX{}} מכיל מגוון של אפשרויות המיועדות עבור משתמשים
הכותבים או קוראים שפות נוספות חוץ מאנגלית. בנוסף לכך, ניתן להתאים
אישית מקשי קיצור, סרגלי כלים ותכונות נוספות רבות. ראה \textsf{עזרה}
\textsf{$\vartriangleleft$התאמה~אישית.}
\item דף הבית של \textenglish{\LyX{}} הוא: \url{http://www.lyx.org}. באתר
זה תוכלו לקבל מידע נוסף על התוכנה, להרשם לרשימות הדיוור וללמוד מהסיור
המודרך של \textenglish{\LyX{}}.\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: After trying, I got: '! Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
      relax 
l.22 \begin{document}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.'

Comment: Dang, I thought that would work for you. There's a chance that this is due to the LyX version. To check this, try running `xelatex` on the LaTeX code that I pasted in my answer. If that doesn't work, my next suggestion would be to 1. install Ubuntu in a virtual box, 2. run https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu 3. install package lyx2.1 from the directions here: http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3 That seems like overkill but I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help...I'll post once I've tried it