# Problem installing culmus-latex on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: lyx, installing, texlive, ubuntu, hebrew

I'm trying to get Hebrew to work for my LaTeX/LyX on Ubuntu 12.04. I have TeX Live 2012 installed and the Hebrew works for that. Then I followed the instructions for installing LyX + Hebrew support, this requires installing the `culmus` LaTeX package. I've gotten this to install as well, however for some reason LaTeX doesn't recognize the file `culmus.sty`.

The path for the file is

`/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/culmus/culmus.sty`

I've also copied the file to my `~/texmf` directory. 
I've run both `mktexlsr` and `texhash`, but when I try to compile a LaTeX file with `\usepackage{culmus}`, I get

> ERROR: LaTeX Error: File `culmus.sty` not found.

In addition, when I save the file in the `~/texmf` directory and compile, I no longer get that error, instead I get:

```
ERROR: I can't find file `jerus10'.

--- TeX said ---
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input jerus10

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input jerus10

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: jerus10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input jerus10' failed to make jerus10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.2 \select@language{hebrew}
```

The file I'm using as a test goes as follows:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{culmus}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
שלום לכל העולם!
\end{document}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Try doing `Tools > Reconfigure`. After that you should get the same error you get at the command line. Note that I can compile your file just fine. I have Hebrew support from the IvriTeX fonts. Note that you could have installed TeX Live and all extra files needed to run all of LyX's templates and examples (including the Hebrew examples) with the following: https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu Note that you need to run `install-tl-ubuntu` with the `--hebrew` option; you might want `--more-tex`. I only recommend this if you have a virtual machine or don't mind reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Another option is to use `XeTeX`. I specify how to do that on Ubuntu in LyX here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137046/xetex-hebrew-pdf-output-problem-in-lyx

Comment: And of course you should update to TL2013 and [install vanilla TL](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu). :-)

Comment: I don't think installing vanilla TL would solve anything since the problem seems to be that the culmus-latex fonts are broken.

Comment: I've just made a clean install of 13.10 and tried again. No luck. I've tried to install ivritex but Ubuntu refuses to install it, claiming an unsolvable dependency issue. So that route doesn't seem to work. However, I've tried going the XeTex route and this seems to do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Ubuntu's (and Debian's) version of `updmap`, a workaround is available in http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2012/04/20/installing-culmus-latex-on-ubuntu-11-10/

(Discalimer: I maintain the [culmus-latex](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex) package)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but not exactly the same problem as yours:

[How do I add Hebrew support to TeXLive on Windows (with pdfTeX+babel)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113367/5640)

similar in that Culmus fonts were not being used and TeXLive was looking for the Jerusalem font's files.

I managed to [work around](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113431/5640) the problem, see if that doesn't work for you, adapting the filenames and/or paths to a Linux setting.

If it *does* work for you, I'll write it up here more nicely...