# Footnote separator is on the wrong direction in Hebrew documents

Tags: xetex, footnotes, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

I am using XeLaTeX and polyglossia for Hebrew typesetting. I have found out that when I am using footnotes (when Hebrew is the default language), they appear on the right direction, but the footnote separator appears in the wrong direction.

This is probably an old issue. I saw [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137489/46188) where a code from LyX is being compiled, and the footnote separator is on the left side. However, they don't treat it as a problem in that thread.

So here I am providing a minimal working example in which the footnote separator is in the wrong side. This is probably a bug (of `polyglossia`?), but even if that's the situation, I'll be glad to know (a) who should I report to about it, and (b) is there any workaround you can think of.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}

\begin{document}
הערת שוליים הנה הערה המופיעה בשוליו\footnote{בדרך כלל בתחתיתו} של ספר או מאמר.
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Comment: I just stumbled upon the same issue. Have you found anything?

Comment: It seems to be already reported for Persian - https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/5  . The bug is from 2011, and still opened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, it's a very old issue, reported already at 2011: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/5

The workaround is simple:
just add `\rightfootnoterule`